# canjs model not populating mustache template

Tags: canjs, canjs-view, canjs-component

I am very new to CanJs just started learning, I am struck with below problem not able to debug it.

I have model as below:

```
Localized = can.Model({
        findOne : 'GET /resources/localized'
    }, {
});
```

GET /resources/localized ---> fetches available localized languages.

And I have defined a component as below

```
can.Component({
    tag : 'preferences',
    template : initView,
    init: function() {
        console.log(locales);
    },
    scope : {
        locales: new LocalizedModel.findOne({})
    }
});
```

initView has mustache template as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>{{dateLayout}}</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="lang" name="lang"  can-change="save">
          {{#list locales.languageOptions}}
              <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
          {{/list}}
      </select>
</div>
```

But the problem is locales are not getting populate, I could see network call for /resources/localized, any pointers here could really help to understand this.

Comment: In the case of your init() function, the reference being logged should be ```this.scope.locales```, not just ```locales```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful to use the correct naming, especially if you were reading up on both EJS and  Mustache building from the CanJS documentation.  The helper that iterates over a list is `{{#each listref}}...{{/each}}` in can.Mustache and can.Stache, where in can.EJS it is `<% list(listref, function(item) { %>...<% }) %>`.  Using `{{#list ...}}` will likely not produce anything.